# How to make this figure better?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to draw figure shown below:
[image]
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, latexsym, mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{pscyr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}

\newcommand{\drawgas}[2]
{
\foreach \a in {0,60,...,360} {%
            \path (#1) ++ (\a:{0.25}) coordinate (r1);            
            \path (#1) ++ (\a:{#2 - 0.25}) coordinate (r2);
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, latex-] (r1) -- (r2);
}
}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[x={(-0.6cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=1.0]
\def\sizeX{16}
\def\sizeY{16}
\def\sizeZ{7}
\def\sizecircleI{4.5}
\def\sizecircleII{3.5}
\def\sizecircleIII{2}
\begin{scope}[line width=1pt, ->]
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (\sizeX+1,0,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,\sizeY+1,0) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\sizeZ+1) node[above] {$z$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
    \draw [black!30] (0,0) grid (\sizeZ,\sizeY);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=0]
    \draw [black!30] (0,0) grid (\sizeZ,\sizeX);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
    \draw [black!30] (0,0) grid (\sizeY,\sizeX);
\end{scope}
%                                               %
\begin{scope}[green, line width=0.5pt]
    \coordinate (p1) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (p2) at (0,0,\sizeZ);
    \coordinate (p3) at (0,\sizeY,\sizeZ);
    \coordinate (p4) at (0,\sizeY,0);
    %
    \coordinate (pp1) at (\sizeX,0,0);
    \coordinate (pp2) at (\sizeX,0,\sizeZ);
    \coordinate (pp3) at (\sizeX,\sizeY,\sizeZ);
    \coordinate (pp4) at (\sizeX,\sizeY,0);
    
    \draw (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4)  (pp1) -- (pp2) -- (pp3) -- (pp4) -- (pp1)  (p2) -- (pp2) (p3) -- (pp3) (p4) -- (pp4);
    \draw[dashed] (p1) -- (p2) (p1) -- (p4) (p1) -- (pp1);
\end{scope}
%                                 %
\begin{scope}[blue, line width=2pt]
    \coordinate (b1) at ($(p2)!.5!(p3) + (0,0,0)$);
    \coordinate (b2) at ($(b1) + (2,0,0)$);
    \coordinate (b3) at ($(b2) + (4,0,0)$);
    \coordinate (b4) at ($(b3) + (0,-3,0)$);%скв
    \coordinate (b5) at ($(b3) + (4,0,0)$);
    \coordinate (b6) at ($(b5) + (0,3,0)$);%скв
    \coordinate (b7) at ($(b5) + (2,0,0)$);%скв
    \fill[black] (b1) circle (6pt);
%   \draw (b1) -- (b2) (b2) -- (b3) (b3) -- (b4) (b3) -- (b5) (b5) -- (b6) (b5) -- (b7);
    \draw (b1) -- (b2) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,100\,mm};
    \draw (b1) -- (b2) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{500\,m}; 
%
    \draw (b2) -- (b3) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,140\,mm};
    \draw (b2) -- (b3) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{1000\,m}; 
%
    \draw (b3) -- (b4) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,140\,mm};
    \draw (b3) -- (b4) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{750\,m}; 
%
    \draw (b3) -- (b5) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,140\,mm};
    \draw (b3) -- (b5) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{1000\,m}; 
%
    \draw (b5) -- (b6) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,140\,mm};
    \draw (b5) -- (b6) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{750\,m}; 
%
    \draw (b5) -- (b7) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,140\,mm};
    \draw (b5) -- (b7) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{500\,m}; 
%
    \fill[red] (b1) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (b2) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (b3) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (b4) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (b5) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (b6) circle (2pt);
    \fill[red] (b7) circle (2pt);
\end{scope}
%             %
\coordinate (z1) at ($(b4) + (0,0,-7.2)$);
\coordinate (z2) at ($(b6) + (0,0,-7.2)$);
\coordinate (z3) at ($(b7) + (0,0,-7.2)$);
%                     %
\begin{scope}
    \clip (z1) circle (\sizecircleI);
    \fill[red!30] (z2) circle (\sizecircleII);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
    \clip (z2) circle (\sizecircleII);
    \fill[red!30] (z3) circle (\sizecircleIII);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[red, dashed, line width=0.5pt]
    \draw (z1) circle (\sizecircleI);
    \draw (z2) circle (\sizecircleII);
    \draw (z3) circle (\sizecircleIII);
    
    \drawgas{z1}{\sizecircleI}
    \drawgas{z2}{\sizecircleII}
    \drawgas{z3}{\sizecircleIII}
\end{scope}
%                                 %
\begin{scope}[line width=1.5pt]
%   \draw (b4) -- (z1) (b6) -- (z2) (b7) -- (z3);
    \draw (z1) -- (b4) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,100\,mm};
    \draw (z1) -- (b4) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{1800\,m}; 
%
    \draw (z2) -- (b6) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,100\,mm};
    \draw (z2) -- (b6) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{1800\,m}; 
%
    \draw (z3) -- (b7) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, above=-1pt]{\diameter\,100\,mm};
    \draw (z3) -- (b7) node [font=\footnotesize, midway, anchor=center, sloped, below=-1pt]{1800\,m}; 
%
\end{scope}
%                                 %
\begin{scope}[black, line width=1.0pt]
    \node[above] at ($(b1) + (0,0,0.3)$) {ITB};
    \draw[latex-] ($(b1) + (0,0.11,0.11)$) -- ++ (0,1,0.5) node[right] {$p_{ITB}$};
    %
    \coordinate (pl_text) at (0,14,7.5);
    \node[above] at (pl_text) {Field};
    \draw[-latex] (pl_text) -- ++ (1,0,-0.5);
    %
    \draw[latex-] ($(b2)!.95!(b3)$) -- ++ (0,-1,1.5) node[left] {Pipeline};
    %
    \draw[latex-] (z3) -- ++ (2,0,1.5) node[left] {$p_{bh}$};
    %
    \draw[latex-] (b7) -- ++ (0,-0.6,0) node[left] {$p_{wh}$};
    %
    \node[above] at (15,2,0) {$p_{rp}$};
    %
    \draw[latex-] ($(b7)!.15!(z3)$) -- ++ (0,-0.6,0) node[left] {Tubing};
    %
    \path (z3) ++ (30:{\sizecircleIII}) coordinate (rpoint);
    \draw[latex-] (rpoint) -- ++ (2,2,0) node[below] {Wells influence contours};
    %
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. How can you make this figure simpler and more effective?
2. How to properly sign the diameter and length of pipes? In my MWE, the pipe is drawn twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps with `\pics`? That is my proposal, anyway.

You can create several `styles` and `\pics` to avoid repeating code: axes, grids, pipelines, and the circles with arrows in the xy plane.

Added to that, I used `siunitx` package for the units, cleaned your code a little, changed the order of some paths for a better visibility and little else.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {siunitx}
\usepackage    {wasysym}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}

\tikzset
{
  axes/.style={line width=1pt,->,shorten >= -1cm},
  green line/.style={green,line width=0.5pt},
  tubing/.style={black, line width=1pt},
  pipeline/.style={blue, line width=2pt},
  pics/my grid/.style 2 args={% (#1,#2) = vertex
      /tikz/transform shape,
      code={%
          \draw[black!30] (0,0) grid (#1,#2);
          \draw[green line] (#1,0) |- (0,#2);
        }},
  pics/axis/.style={% #1 = length
      code={%
        \draw[line width=1pt,->] (O) -- ($(O#1)!-1cm!(O)$);
        \draw[green line,dashed] (O) -- (O#1);
        \node at ($(O#1)!-1.25cm!(O)$) {$\i$};
      }},
  pics/dimension/.style n args={3}{% #1 = second point, #2 diameter, #3 = length
        code={%
          \draw (0,0,0) -- (#1) node[midway,above=-1pt,sloped,font=\footnotesize] {\diameter\,\qty{#2}{\milli\meter}}
                                node[midway,below=-1pt,sloped,font=\footnotesize] {\qty{#3}{\meter}};
        }},
    pics/drawgas/.style={% #1 = radius
        code={%
            \draw[red,dashed,line width=0.5pt] (0,0) circle [radius=#1];
            \foreach \a in {0,60,...,300} 
                \draw[red,dashed,line width=0.5pt, latex-] (\a:0.25) -- (\a:#1-0.25);
        }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.6cm,-0.4cm)}, y={(1cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]
% dimensions
\def\sizeX{16}
\def\sizeY{16}
\def\sizeZ{7}
\def\sizecircleI{4.5}
\def\sizecircleII{3.5}
\def\sizecircleIII{2}
% coordinates
\coordinate (O)    at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (Ox)   at (\sizeX,0,0);
\coordinate (Oy)   at (0,\sizeY,0);
\coordinate (Oz)   at (0,0,\sizeZ);
\coordinate (Oxy)  at (\sizeX,\sizeY,0);
\coordinate (Oyz)  at (0,\sizeY,\sizeZ);
\coordinate (Oxz)  at (\sizeX,0,\sizeZ);
\coordinate (Oxyz) at (\sizeX,\sizeY,\sizeZ);
\coordinate (b1)   at (0,0.5*\sizeY,\sizeZ);
\coordinate (b2)   at ($(b1) + (2,0,0)$);
\coordinate (b3)   at ($(b2) + (4,0,0)$);
\coordinate (b4)   at ($(b3) + (0,-3,0)$);
\coordinate (b5)   at ($(b3) + (4,0,0)$);
\coordinate (b6)   at ($(b5) + (0,3,0)$);
\coordinate (b7)   at ($(b5) + (2,0,0)$);
\coordinate (z1)   at ($(b4) + (0,0,-7.2)$);
\coordinate (z2)   at ($(b6) + (0,0,-7.2)$);
\coordinate (z3)   at ($(b7) + (0,0,-7.2)$);
% grids
\pic[canvas is xy plane at z=0] {my grid={\sizeX}{\sizeY}};
\pic[canvas is xz plane at y=0] {my grid={\sizeX}{\sizeZ}};
\pic[canvas is yz plane at x=0] {my grid={\sizeY}{\sizeZ}};
% axes
\foreach\i in {x,y,z}
    \pic {axis={\i}};
% circles intersection
\begin{scope}
    \clip         (z2) circle [radius=\sizecircleII];
    \fill[red!30] (z1) circle [radius=\sizecircleI];
    \fill[red!30] (z3) circle [radius=\sizecircleIII];
\end{scope}
% ITB
\fill[black] (b1) circle (6pt);
% black tubing                              %
\begin{scope}[tubing]
    \pic at (z1) {dimension={b4}{100}{1800}};
    \pic at (z2) {dimension={b6}{100}{1800}};
    \pic at (z3) {dimension={b7}{100}{1800}};
\end{scope}
% blue pipelines
\begin{scope}[pipeline]
    \pic at (b1) {dimension={b2}{100}{500}};
    \pic at (b2) {dimension={b3}{140}{1000}};
    \pic at (b3) {dimension={b4}{140}{750}};
    \pic at (b3) {dimension={b5}{140}{1000}};
    \pic at (b5) {dimension={b6}{140}{750}};
    \pic at (b5) {dimension={b7}{140}{500}};
\end{scope}
% red cricles with arrows
\foreach[count=\ii]\i in {\sizecircleI,\sizecircleII,\sizecircleIII}
   \pic at (z\ii) {drawgas={\i}};
% labels (unchanged)                                %
\begin{scope}[black, line width=1.0pt]
    \node[above] at ($(b1) + (0,0,0.3)$) {ITB};
    \draw[latex-] ($(b1) + (0,0.11,0.11)$) -- ++ (0,1,0.5) node[right] {$p_{ITB}$};
    \coordinate (pl_text) at (0,14,7.5);
    \node[above] at (pl_text) {Field};
    \draw[-latex] (pl_text) -- ++ (1,0,-0.5);
    \draw[latex-] ($(b2)!.95!(b3)$) -- ++ (0,-1,1.5) node[left] {Pipeline};
    \draw[latex-] (z3) -- ++ (2,0,1.5) node[left] {$p_{bh}$};
    \draw[latex-] (b7) -- ++ (0,-0.6,0) node[left] {$p_{wh}$};
    \node[above] at (15,2,0) {$p_{rp}$};
    \draw[latex-] ($(b7)!.15!(z3)$) -- ++ (0,-0.6,0) node[left] {Tubing};
    \path (z3) ++ (30:{\sizecircleIII}) coordinate (rpoint);
    \draw[latex-] (rpoint) -- ++ (2,2,0) node[below] {Wells influence contours};
\end{scope}
% points
\foreach\i in {1,...,7}
    \fill[red] (b\i) circle (2pt);
% more green lines
\foreach\i in {xy,xz,yz}
    \draw[green line] (Oxyz) -- (O\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm not posting the picture, because it's essentially the same as in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Juan Castaño. But your example does not compile for me. Error in line: Undefined control sequence. \pic at (z1) {dimension={b4}{100}{1800}}

Comment: @Youra_P, a wild guess: could it be `siunitx`? If you don't have the last version change `\qty{ }{}` for `\SI{ }{ }` in the `\pic` code.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Juan Castaño .